# Fan speed still at 850 RPM at 0% speed

Tags: cpu, speedfan

I have SpeedFan 4.49 installed with my goal to make my tower as silent as possible.

My CPU is the Intel i5 2500k and even at 0% in SpeedFan, I still have 850 RPM.

[image]

For normal office work I think this is still too loud. My guess is that 400-500 RPM would be better for me.

Is there a way to get there?

Comment: You might have a BIOS setting for minimum speed. Otherwise, a [10 ohm, 1/2 watt resistor](http://www.radioshack.com/product/index.jsp?productId=2062309) in the 12V line to the fan should do it.

Comment: in your pic it is shown that speedfan is not yet in control (a safety feature) "Automatic fan speed" is not yet selected.  Some designs that speedfan will control will never go below a certain percentage of speed .  Some fans will not turn or start, at too low of speed, although much of the new stuff using PWM will start (even slow) from a stopped state. The controls for speedfan take some time to work. ALSO (but not required) in [Config] Fan Control tab "advanced fan control" you can create a graph which will include stopping if the hardware makes it possible.  It takes some time to figure it

Comment: In the simple configuration , you have to set everything. one thing that controls the lowest and highest speeds is in the Speeds tab itself select the Fan item and at the bottom the min and max are shown and settable. When you get things more under control and understood you will start seeing everything more clearly, but you gotta tweak it and get a feel for what occurs, it takes much time, even with a guide.

Comment: @Psycogeek But the question is: Can I get under 850 RPM?

Comment: I do not know. 850 would be high , and a 500-600 should be possible in almost any system, even if that means a different fan. In my systems i actually replace the fans with high speed ones ?? Then use anything they provide or I can get to control it, for both super quiet and for full load in high ambient temps (california).  If all else fails there are fans with Thermal Sencors and control on the fan itself (reads the temps of the air passing by). If it is PWM percentage max low, then a slower fan would have a slower speed. that is why it has not been logical the lack of control on some things